# Remove file name and extension from path and just keep path

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Hi I have a string like this which will be dynamic and can be in following combinations.

```
'new/file.csv'
'new/mainfolder/file.csv'
'new/mainfolder/subfolder/file.csv'
'new/mainfolder/subfolder/secondsubfolder/file.csv'
```

Something like these. In any case I just want this string in 2 parts like  path and filename. Path will not consist of file name for example.

End result expected

```
    'new'
    'new/mainfolder'
    'new/mainfolder/subfolder'
    'new/mainfolder/subfolder/secondsubfolder'
```

Till now tried many things included

```
path = 'new/mainfolder/file.csv'
final_path = path.split('/', 1)[-1]
```

And `rstrip()` but nothing worked till now.

Comment: Next time please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Look at [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Comment: May be it's a typo, but you should've tried `rsplit` instead of `rstrip`. This should work: `path,name=string.rsplit('/',1)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for this.

For example,

```
>>>import pathlib
>>>path = pathlib.Path('new/mainfolder/file.csv')
>>>path.name
'file.csv'
>>>str(path.parent)
'new/mainfolder'
```

Answer (score 1):

An option to pathlib is `os`

```
import os
fullPath = 'new/mainfolder/file.csv'
parent = os.path.dirname(fullPath) # get path only
file = os.path.basename(fullPath) # get file name

print (parent)
```

Output:

```
new/mainfolder
```

path.dirname:

> Return the directory name of pathname path. This is the first element of the pair returned by passing path to the function split(). Source: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname

path.basename:

> Return the base name of pathname path. This is the second element of the pair returned by passing path to the function split(). Note that the result of this function is different from the Unix basename program; where basename for '/foo/bar/' returns 'bar', the basename() function returns an empty string ('').
> Source: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename

Answer (score 0):

you almost got it, just use `rsplit`, like this:

```
path = 'new/mainfolder/file.csv'

file_path, file_name = path.rsplit('/', 1)

print(f'{file_path=}\n{file_name=}')
'''
file_path='new/mainfolder'
file_name='file.csv'
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
  input  = ['new/file.csv',
'new/mainfolder/file.csv',
'new/mainfolder/subfolder/file.csv',
'new/mainfolder/subfolder/secondsubfolder/file.csv']

output = []
for i in input:
  i = i.split("/")[:-1]
  i = "/".join(i)
  output.append(i)

print(output)
```

Output:

```py
['new', 'new/mainfolder', 'new/mainfolder/subfolder', 'new/mainfolder/subfolder/secondsubfolder']
```